# Sort a map in a specific order

Tags: java

I have the following object:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Serializable>> resultList;
```

Which contains these values:

```
{
for_closing={count=3, status=For closing}, 
overdue={count=1, status=Overdue}, 
closed={count=1, status=Closed}, 
for_action={count=3, status=For action}
}
```

I'd like to sort this Map in a specific order (for_action, for_closing, closed, overdue), maybe with an enum or something? After the sort resultList will have this ordering:

```
{
for_action={count=3, status=For action}
for_closing={count=3, status=For closing}, 
closed={count=1, status=Closed}, 
overdue={count=1, status=Overdue}, 
}
```

Comment: You mean like a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)?

Comment: @bradimus not really  (the op doesn't want alphabetical order) - a LinkedHashMap would probably be a better candidate for that job.

Comment: I think you should step back and reconsider your data structure. This looks ... strange. And side note: dont upt the "collection" type into your variable names. And hint: calling something result**List** that is actually a MAP, exactly proves that point.

Comment: @assylias How do you sort a `LinkedHashMap`? `TreeMap` allows you to specify the `Comparator`. As does `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

Comment: Why do you care what order they are in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an Enum in your desired order:

```
public enum Tasks {
    FOR_ACTION,
    FOR_CLOSING,
    CLOSED,
    OVERDUE
}
```

Then create a TreeMap using the Enum as key.

`TreeMap<Tasks, Map<String, Serializable>> resultList`;

Comment: Your Tasks need to be comparable or you will get an exception at runtime.

Comment: Enums in Java extend comparable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html